# Loading a csv with pd.read_csv and returning a df with column names parsed from the header

Tags: pandas, csv, parsing, header

Given a csv like:

[image: Given a csv like in the link]

How can I load it into a pandas df (e.g., with pd.read_csv()) such that it looks like the dataframe below:

[image: How can I load it into a pandas df (e.g., with pd.read_csv()) such that it looks like the dataframe in this link?]

Answer (score 0):

```
def load_csv(filename):
    category = pd.read_csv(filename, nrows=0).columns.str.replace('(\.\d+)$','')
    category_subset = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=1, nrows=0).columns.str.replace('\:.*','').str.replace('(\.\d+)$','')
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=2)
    df.columns = category + ": " + category_subset + ": " + df.columns
    return df
```

I came up with this. But it's so ugly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).